# How to make Javascript timer work for variable parameter

Tags: javascript, timer

The Javascript timer event has this basic syntax:

```
var t=setTimeout("javascript statement",milliseconds);
```

I have this function that gets called onkeyup() for some text box. I want the `numeric_value_search()` function to be called after a certain amount of time, which is 5 seconds in this example.

The key line is the 5th line. I have four different ways that it might be written, each of which gives the specified error:

```
    timer=setTimeout(numeric_value_search(boundBox),5000);
```

ERROR: useless setTimeout call (missing quotes around argument?)

```
    timer=setTimeout("numeric_value_search(boundBox)",5000);
```

ERROR: boundBox is not defined

```
    timer=setTimeout("numeric_value_search("+boundBox+")",5000);
```

ERROR: missing ] after element list

```
    timer=setTimeout(numeric_value_search("+boundBox),5000);
```

ERROR: data is passed nicely and there are no explicit errors but the timer doesn't work

```
var timer;
function chk_me(boundBox){
console.info(boundBox.id);
    clearTimeout(timer);
//  --- timer code here ---   e.g. timer=setTimeout("numeric_value_search("+boundBox+")",5000);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
setTimeout(function() {
    numeric_value_search(boundBox);
}, 5000);
```

Comment: +1, this is the only way to use setTimeout which is both correct and clean.

Answer (score 3):

As @kgiannakakis already said,

```
setTimeout(function() {
    numeric_value_search(boundBox);
}, 5000);
```

is the way to go.

The reason is simple: When using a string argument it's like using `eval()` which is usually evil. When passing a function however you not only avoid putting code inside a string (which breaks syntax highlighting and might require escape orgies) but also have the possibility of using a closure to access variables in the current context without embedding them into a string (which might lead to code injection if not done properly).